Unable to test my catalyst application in local machine using the command "catalyst serve"
I tried testing my catalyst application which contains advanced I/O functions and a web client using the command "catalyst serve" but I am getting the error

"No ports in the range 3040 to 3060 is free"

Can someone help  me resolve this?

As the error message indicates, the ports from 3040 to 3060 in your local machine are not available for catalyst process to spawn servers for your function. There can be any number of reasons for this issue, like some other background process is holding those ports or the ports might not have closed properly.
To find if any process are running on the ports 3040 to 3060 you can use the below command:
lsof -i :3040-3060 -P -n

The above command will list any and all process that are running in the ports 3040-3060 from which you can retreive the PID(Process ID) for each process.
Once you obtained the PID you can kill those process using the below command
kill <<PID>>

Replace <<PID>> with the actual Process ID you obtained from the lsof command. Once you have killed all the process, you can re-check if any process are still running using the lsof command. If you don't receive any response, then there are no process that running on the ports 3040 to 3060.
You can then try testing your catalyst function using the below command which should start your functions properly:
catalyst serve

If the above solution doesn't work, you can try restarting your machine and check if you are able to run your catalyst functions.
